# Query db with in exlusion

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to query db. I need to show all fields, but need to exclude one name that is in the db.

**Example:**

The db contains column `'marketer'` when I try to query it I don't want marketer `'Tommy'` but all the others. I have tried tried where clause with all the names and not working.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query you're looking for

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE marketer<>'Tommy';
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. Racking my brain trying to figure this out. And when its as simple as the above statement makes me feel noobish :X

Answer (score 0):

use the `'where'` to add your conditions

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE marketer!='Tommy'
```

**For your Reference**

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp